# Efficient/Fast Complex Airy function implementation on Mathematica (Ai and Ai')

Tags: special-functions

Is there a speedier compiled version for an efficient implementation for the complex Airy function (Ai and Ai') on Mathematica?

Comment: Speedier than...what? The built-in symbol `AiryAi`?

Comment: Mathematica special functions are usually slow. For example, the Digamma function is very slow and one needs to use the Compile of strip down/minimal code to achieve proper speed for applications such as minimization or nonlinear fits. I am asking if someone did this already instead of re-inventing the wheel!

Comment: Have you tried just simply compiling `AiryAi`?

Comment: AiryAi is not a compilable function.  It just calls MainEvaluate

Comment: I suppose by Digamma you mean `PolyGamma[0, z]`, but if you use `Compile` on `PolyGamma` it does not run any faster. The runtime environment calls the regular `PolyGamma` function via `MainEvaluate`. If anything, it runs slower. -- The Mathematica `AiryAi` and the MATLAB `airy` take about the same time on machine-precision complex arrays.

Comment: I tried timing MATLAB repeatedly, and the timings vary quite a bit. AFAICT, `airy(z)` is much faster in MATLAB than Mathematica. My guess is that the first timing included a one-time initialization for computing `airy(z)`.

Comment: Sorry, but both Digamma=PolyGamma[z] and trigamma=PolyGamma[1,z] are slow even with Compile.

Answer (score 4):

Interpolation, via the trapezoidal rule applied to the Cauchy integral formula, is a standard approach when the domain can be limited to a fairly small disk in the complex plane over which the function is analytic.

```
z0 = 1 + I;   (* center of disk *)
rr = 2;       (* radius of disk *)
nn = 128;     (* number of interpolation nodes *)
tt = CirclePoints[nn] . {1., 1. I}*rr/nn;          (* dz = rr I Exp[I t] dt *)
zz = CirclePoints[N@ReIm@z0, rr, nn] . {1., 1. I}; (* interpolation nodes *)
ff = AiryAi[zz];        (* precomputed function values *)
aic = Compile[{{a, _Complex}},
   (ff/(zz - a)) . tt,  (* tt = dz / (2 Pi I) *)
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True, 
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];
```

Example:

```
z1 = RandomPoint[Disk[ReIm@z0, rr]] . {1., 1. I};
aic[z1]
% - AiryAi[z1]
(*
  -0.5794777994960615` - 0.8256941573359182` I 
  -5.21805*10^-15 - 6.32827*10^-15 I
*)
```

Timing:

```
z1 = RandomPoint[Disk[ReIm@z0, rr], 10000] . {1., 1. I};
AiryAi[z1]; // RepeatedTiming // First
aic[z1]; // RepeatedTiming // First
%%/%
(*
  0.964271
  0.0139345
  69.2
*)
```

Comment: Very nice......

Comment: Thanks ........

Comment: Did you consider the AAA algorithm for interpolation over the complex plane? https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/16M1106122
It optimizes the nodes!